# C++ Custom event for default controls in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, events, mouseevent, qlineedit

Is it possible to write custom event reaction and add it to default controls like QLineEdit. I have own QSplashScreen with few controls like QLabel, QLineEdit or QPushButton. For one of them I need to customize reaction for mousePressEvent. How to do that? I haven't want create new MyQLineEdit which inherit QLineEdit, I only want override default event function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `installEventFilter()` + implement `eventFilter()`, see [the sample](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) from Qt Docs. But instead of `MainWindow` there will be you custom SplashScreen.

Answer (score 0):

You can install an event filter for your QLineEdit. For more information see [Event Filters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters)